# Headless режим в Api "Dolphin Anty" selenium

Tags: python, api, selenium, headless

Я использую Api антидетект браузера "Dolphin anty" с python selenium и хочу включить Headless режим, но в этом API команды `options.headless = True` и `options.addarguments( --headless )` не работают :(

У кого-нибудь есть какие-либо идеи?

Answer (score 0):

При отправке запроса на старт профиля указать нужно

```
&headless=0/1
0 - false
1 - true
```